# Put image on div randomly using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, random

I am making matching game that images in left and right are different, and users have to find(I put one more image in left side).
My problem is that I cannot call image on where I want. What should I have to fix? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      position: absolute;
    }
    div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    #leftside {
      float: left;
    }
    #rightside {
      float: right;
      left: 500px;
      border-left: 1px solid black
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var numberOfFaces(5);
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

    function generateFaces() {
      var createElement("img");
      var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
      img.src = 'http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png';
      img.id = 'smileImage';
      createElement.setAttribute("height", position);
      createElement.setAttribute("width", position);
      document.getElementById('leftSide').appendChild(img);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Matching Game</h1>
  <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>
  <div id="leftside"></div>
  <div id="rightside"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Mind clarifying what you mean by "call image?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set something to the result of `createElement('img')`. For example, you can change that line to `var img = createElement('img');`

You never actually use `theLeftSide`.

`createElement` is actually `document.createElement`.

You never defined the variable `createElement`. Since we called it `img` earlier, do so now.

`leftSide` is not the ID of any element, but `leftside` is. Change it so that all usages are capitalized the same.

After that, you actually need to call `generateFaces`. Because the page is loaded top-to-bottom, JavaScript doesn't yet know about the `div` with the ID of `leftSide`. You have to wait until the page is finished loading to call the Javascript, and you can do that by adding `window.onload = generateFaces` to the end of your script.

Here's the final result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      position: absolute;
    }
    div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    #leftside {
      float: left;
    }
    #rightside {
      float: right;
      left: 500px;
      border-left: 1px solid black
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function generateFaces() {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
      img.src = 'http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png';
      img.id = 'smileImage';
      img.setAttribute('height', position);
      img.setAttribute('width', position);
      document.getElementById('leftSide').appendChild(img);
    }
    window.onload = generateFaces;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Matching Game</h1>
  <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>
  <div id="leftSide"></div>
  <div id="rightSide"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just noticed that small mistake can change a lot in coding. Thank you for your excellent advice. I have one more question that its position. As you see in my code, I made position variable for its position, but seems I made it for its size. Can you tell me how to set its position(location?) Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough CSS to help, so I'd ask a new question. Just out of curiosity, is JavaScript your first language or are you coming from a C++ background?

Comment: I am really newbie, but have little knowledge in Java. I appreciate your answer. I am now trying put random location for my image, not random size lol

Comment: Just FYI, I figured out random location and made few more duplicated images on random location.

Comment: Perfect! I'm glad I could help.